# How to make css class turn back to before on click css jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so I have a `<div>` with  a blue background color,with a jquery onclick event that changes color of that div to red. I was wondering how I could go about making the div background color change back to blue when the button is clicked again & turn back to red if click again and like that?

Comment: Hello, and welcome :) it is always best to post an example code on what you have already tried. This way it will be easiest to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you **exactly** mean by *clicking twice*, so I've made two possible solutions for you.

First box changes it's background to `blue` on **one** click and changes back into `black`, when clicked **twice** (double click).

Second box changes it's background with every click, one time it's `green` and one time it's `yellow`.

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box'),
    box2 = document.getElementById('box2'),
    bool = true;
    
    box.addEventListener('click', function(){
      this.style.background = 'blue';
    });

    box.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){
      this.style.background = 'black';
    });

    box2.addEventListener('click', function(){
      if (bool) {
        this.style.background = 'yellow';
        bool = false;
      } else {
        this.style.background = 'green';
        bool = true;
      }
    });
```

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin: 5px;
}
#box2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'></div>
<div id='box2'></div>
```

Comment: Thankc :D got it, I mean it's change background on every click :D

Comment: @RizalFakhri Then the second solution, with a `boolean`-helping variable will be suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need This.

```
$(".yourDiv").click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("red");
});
```

Your CSS

```
.yourDiv{ background-color: #1E90FF; }
.yourDiv.red { background-color:#FF0000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

your gonig to need to share some code for a sample on how your problem would be solved. But the most common way would be to have your jquery onclick event check the color of the div using code similar to:

```
var theColorIs = $('a').css("backgroundColor");
```

then having it change colors based on what the color currently is

Answer (score 0):

You can use pass an empty string to `.css` in jQuery, like `.css('background-color', '');`, to clear previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a method called toggleClass which is ideal for this. You should also look at the toggle method.

```
 <style>
 .blue{
      background-color: blue;
 }
 .red{
      background-color: red;
 }
 </style>

 <div class="blue">
      ....
 </div>

 <script>

 $( ".blue, .red" ).click(function() {
   $( this ).toggleClass("blue");
   $( this ).toggleClass("red");
 });
</script>
```

p.s. im typing on a phone

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery necessary, all you need to do is add some styling to a CSS class and add/remove the class via Vanilla JavaScript.

```js
let body = document.querySelector('body'),
    box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let cl = e.target.classList;
  if (cl.contains('box'))
    cl.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: blue;
  display:    inline-block;
  margin:     5px;
  height:     2.5rem;
  width:      2.5rem;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

- binds click event to the parent element (in this case the body).  This is important because instead of creating 5 click functions for the browser to handle, there's only one
- because the *click* is attached to the *body* element, we have to look at what the event target was of the click (what was actually clickeD) in order to determine if it was a box (or just a body).  We can determine if it was a box by checking for the class.
  If you want to explore this more, remove the if statement and re-run the code.  Then click on the white space.  You'll notice that because we were not looking for boxes, it'll add the *active* class to any element that was clicked.

For even shorter code you can remove replace the whole *if* block with `cl.contains('box') && cl.toggle('active');`, which says "if the element has a *box* class, then toggle the *active* class"